# Water Drop Cocos2d-X

Tags: android, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

Hey is it possible makes a water drop with Box2D in cocos2d-x?

Some said that Box2D and Chipmunk focus on rigid body, making it very difficult to create soft object..

i followed 
[this](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2012/05/16/simulating-mudslime-with-box2d-bitmaps-and-filters/)
 article, but cocos2d-x doesn't support for filter or threshold...

I've been searching for hours, and even considering to create water drop with particle(is it possible)?

Any help would be appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following tutorial shows how to do something similar with cocos2d v3.x (objective-c, but you can definitely get some inspiration): http://2sa-studio.blogspot.com/2014/05/soft-bodies-with-cocos2d-v3.html.

The idea is to use multiple bodies connected with springs and to override the `draw` method of the sprite to map the texture according to the bodies' positions.